# Most efficient way to write a byte matrix to text file

Tags: java, byte, text-files, bufferedwriter

I have a problem in Java writing a 3D byte matrix (as unsigned bytes) to a text file.
The matrix is 3D and looks like `wMatrix3D[k][j][i]`. I want to it to a textfile so the values are separated by white space and a new line break every 1,000 values (there are 1,000 pixel values per row and 1,000 rows making a 1,000 x 1,000 text file representing an image).

Currently, I do it like this:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(imgout));

//Parse Headers
for(int countHeaderLines = 0; countHeaderLines < numHeaders; countHeaderLines+=1){
    out.write(headers[countHeaderLines] + "\n");
}
System.out.println("Wrote Headers");

//Parse 1,000,000 x 1,000 2D matrix into 3D (1,000 x 1,000) x 1,000 matrix 
System.out.println("Writing main matrix to text...");

//String slice = new String();
for(int k = 0; k < numLayers; k++){
    for(int j = 0;  j < numRows; j++){
        String rowStr = new String();
        for(int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++){
            rowStr += Integer.toString((Integer.valueOf(wMatrix3D[k][j][i]) & 0xFF)) + " ";
        }
    out.write(rowStr + "\n");
    }

/*if( (k+1) % 5 == 0){
slice = new String();
out.write(slice);
System.out.println("Writing Set of 10:" + k);
}*/

System.out.println("k: " + k);
}
```

However, this way is VERY VERY slow. is there a more efficient way to do this? In C I have no problem using "fprintf" but in Java I just cannot get it to work well.

Comment: Why do you want to arrange the data in such a way (1000x1000 with spaces)? Is it worth the time penalty?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing 1 billion integers on a file, so assuming a minimum of 1 byte per number + 1 byte per white space, ignoring newlines you are already a 2 gigabytes of data that must be written on disk.

Now this is a good amount that will surely require time but you could consider using a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) around your `BufferedWriter` so that you can use directly many other operations that could be more optimized, eg

```
void print(int i)
```

In addition it seems that your matrix is stored as strings (because you use `Integer.valueOf(...)`) to convert strings to integers, then you AND them and convert back again. I guess you could **save some time by already having everything as int** (or in any case this seems more senseful).

Consider also using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead that concatenating on a long string like you're doing. But I don't think you should concatenate anything at all (by using `PrintWriter` and optimize data structure).

If your data is not meant to be readable by humans, then just skip strings and **save binary data**, you'll gain at least 10x in speed.

Comment: I think StringBuilder is not a really good idea, since the memory may run out before it reaches 1G numbers.

Comment: On the contrary, StringBuilder is almost essential here, just use it per line and you will be fine.  Btw @jack, as this is converting bytes to string, your maths is slightly out, it's 3-bytes per number + 1 per space, so 4GB.

Comment: @Recurse: I wrote a minimum of 1 + 1, so it was a lower bound assuming that in the best case every number is < 10 so you just need 1 byte. When you see that a lower bound is already a huge amount, like in this case, there's no need to assume the worst :) In any case I keep being unable to see the point of storing them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that you are effectively executing the central loop 1 billion times. There's nothing you can do to reduce that because that is the number of values in your 3d array. All you can hope to do is make that loop as tight as possible.

Creating strings by 'adding' (using the + operator) is very inefficient. Reducing the number of strings you create (which occurs every time you use the + operator to concatenate them) will help. Look into using a StringBuilder instead.

```
StringBuilder rowStr = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    rowStr.append(...);
    ...
rowStr.append("\n");
out.write(rowStr.toString());
```

Also, don't use Integer.toString on the result of Integer.valueOf. Try just casting to int and handling the case where the result is negative.

Any time you can remove the construction of a new object in the inner loop, you will be saving time.

Answer (score 0):

`Array`s and `byte`s are both `Serializable` in Java.  Simply write the array to a file via an `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

class MatrixWriter {
    public static void main(String... a) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        byte[][][] data = new byte[][][] {
                { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } },
                { { 9, 10 }, { 11, 12 } } };
        String filename = "data.ser";

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                filename));
        out.writeObject(data);
        out.close();

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                filename));
        byte[][][] array = (byte[][][]) in.readObject();
        in.close();

        for (byte[][] b : array) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (byte[] c : b) {
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c));
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jason Are you sure?  Unless I've missed it, he didn't state that as a requirement.

Comment: That's what he has taken great lengths to do in his code. He didn't say his code was wrong - just that it was incredibly slow.

Comment: He did say "text file" several times in the question. "human-readable", was how I read the question also.

Comment: @Jason You may be absolutely right - but that is not my interpretation of the question, especially as written in the title.  No harm done if my answer's not of use.  (Also, I'd debate that a text file with millions of integers is readable.  :])

Comment: @cheeken If you do it right, you can zoom out and tadah: ASCII art. :P

Comment: @cheeken Ok, I'll accept that. Especially as any file with ~4000 characters per line is likewise, only technically human readable.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the input you are getting in the other answers are correct. But the best way to find out whats causing the performance problem is to profile your application. Netbeans IDE actually has a decent profiler built-in. If you were to profile your application, preferably with a subset of the matrix (I tried 200^3 iterations), you'll notice String manipulation is your problem.

[image]

Each time you concatenate a strings you are creating a `String` object in the background. As other answers have made you aware, you're doing that a billion times. So the first step towards a good solution is to stop creating objects at each iteration. This can be done through use of `StringBuilder` by using `append()` to concatenate values and `setLength(0)` to reuse the character array. This will produce slight improvement since only 1 string is created at each iteration. Another way is to call `out.write()` using each string you'd like to write without having to concatenate them. You can see results below:

**Using StringBuilder:**

[image]

**Direct to BufferedWriter:**

[image]

FYI, I've read that [Memory Mapped Files](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm) improve file write speeds. The only downside I've seen is that you'd have to know the expected file size beforehand.